# Detect Fluid Pathlines in Images

Tags: python, fluid-dynamics

I have several thousand images of fluid pathlines -- below is a simple example --

[image]

and I would like to automatically detect them: Length and position.
For the position a defined point would be sufficient (e.g. left end).
I don't need the full shape information.

This is a pretty common task but I did not find a reliable method.

How could I do this?

My choice would be Python but it's no necessity as long as I can export the results.

---

**EDIT**

This is a rough draft of what I'm searching for:

[image: example]

I need the length of the lines and e.g. the coordinates of the red dot.

Answer (score 0):

[Counting curves, angles and straights in a binary image in openCV and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72099560/counting-curves-angles-and-straights-in-a-binary-image-in-opencv-and-python) pretty much answers your question.
I tried it on your image and it works.

I used:

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

and commented out these two lines:

```
pts = remove_straight(pts)      # remove almost straight angles
pts = max_corner(pts) # remove nearby points with greater angle
```

[image]

Comment: You you for your answer! Could you explain in what way this is working? I don't understand in what way the points are related to my question.

Comment: It is possible to determine the points in the fluid pathlines by tweaking the cv2.threshold parameters, which as far as I understood was what you wanted to do.

Comment: Vandan Revanur: I added a sketch of what I mean to the question.